# How to hide top app bar in React Native Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I'm using react-native-navigation package for navigation but here I'm unable to hide Top AppBar.
How can I do that?

> [Here is the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAp2r.png)

Here is my code:

```
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";

Navigation.registerComponent("Home", () => App);
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(async () => {
    Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
            stack: {
                children: [
                    {
                        component: {
                            name: "Home",
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    });
});

// I tried this, but it is not completely hiding AppBar. 
// Small AppBar is still showing there
App.options = {
    topBar: { visible: false }, 
};
```

Comment: You want to hide the header at the top, containing the back to button and the name of the current screen.

Comment: Yes yes exactly